# How do I define the index? Why do i see the error: a non-numeric value encountered?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use the name of the table's indexes. However upon launching my webpage I see the following errors:

> undefined index on lines 73, 75,76,77,79 and 80.

What am I doing wrong here and how I can rectify it.

The undefined indexes in question are:

```
id, pname, price and image.
```

Index:

[image: index]

My code:

```
  <div class="container" style="width: 65%">
        <h2>Ticket Cart</h2>
        <?php
        $query = $handle->query('SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC');

            while ($row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


        }
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row ["id"]?>"> // line 73
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive"> // line 75
                    <h5 class = "text-info"><?php $row["pname"]; ?> </h5> //line 76
                    <h5 class="text-danger"><?php $row["price"]; ?></h5> //line77
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["pname"]; ?>"> // line 79
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>"> // line 80
                    <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success"
                           value="Add to Cart">

                </div>

            </form>
    </div>
```

Below are the lines 154 and 160 where i am receiving the error: non numeric value:

```
$ <?php echo number_format($value["item_quantity"] * $value["product_price"], 2); ?></td> // line 154

 $total = $total + ($value["item_quantity"] * $value["product_price"]); // line 160
```

Comment: `while ($row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){` I don't think, you want to fetch all rows in this single call. `$query->fetch` should be the method you want to use

Comment: @kuh-chan Thanks, that worked. but now i have the errors: non numeric value on lines 154 and 160, i will update the post to show those lines.

Comment: @WillSmith now you are mixing several questions into one. Your second problem could be that either `item_quantity` or `product_price` has a non-numeric value, i.e. `NULL`.

Comment: @SaschaM78 i managed to find out why i was seeing the error, the cause of it is deeper routed within the code.

Comment: @WillSmith if you think it's worth sharing, please add your finding as a separate answer to your own question and mark it as your solution. That would be highly appreciated for other users that may come here with a comparable problem. Nice to hear you could solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

in order to get past the first error I was having, which was the undefined index I needed to add the following code to the start of the file:

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])){
    if (isset($_SESSION["cart"])){
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"],"product_id");
        if (!in_array($_GET["id"],$item_array_id)){
            $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
                'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
            );
            $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
            echo '<script>window.location="Cart.php"</script>';
        }else{
            echo '<script>alert("Product is already Added to Cart")</script>';
            echo '<script>window.location="Cart.php"</script>';
        }
    }else{
        $item_array = array(
            'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The main problem of your code is that the `while` loop ends before you think you would output the received rows' output. The `index` does not have any reference to a database index but it simply means you are accessing an object `$row` with an index that does not exist like "pname" or "price".

Change the code accordingly:

```
<?php
$query = $handle->query('SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC');

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

?>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]?>"> // line 73
        <div class="product">
            <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive"> // line 75
            <h5 class = "text-info"><?php $row["pname"]; ?> </h5> //line 76
            <h5 class="text-danger"><?php $row["price"]; ?></h5> //line77
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["pname"]; ?>"> // line 79
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>"> // line 80
            <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success"
                   value="Add to Cart">

        </div>

    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i managed to get past that issue through removing fetchAll and just replacing with fetch. The issue i am facing now is  the error: non-numeric value encountered on lies 154 and 160, i have updated the post